# How to use Linq to Split a String on newlines and space?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a string:

```
string data = 
"item1  actived
 item2  none
 item special I none
 item special II actived"
```

you can see 4 rows in the data.
I need to split a string into a List item as below:

```
item[0]={Name=item1, Status=actived}
item[1]={Name=item2, Status=none}
item[2]={Name=item Special I, Status=none}
item[3]={Name=item Special II, Status=actived}
```

I'm tried:

```
var s = SplitReturn(data);
public string[] SplitReturn(string name)
{
    return name.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
}
```

How do I can Split space in my string and then convert to List?

Comment: So what is your question (not requirement)?

Comment: Without showing what you have tried see how fast it is downvoted....

Comment: is the string "item1  actived item2  none item special I none item special II actived" or is it "item1  actived \n\ritem2  none \n\ritem special I none\n\r item special II actived"

Comment: Oh.downvoted.yes, they are \r\n.please se e my update.@Neil

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string data =
    @"item1 actived
     item2 none

     item special I none
     item special II actived";

var result = data.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(item => {
        int lastSpace = item.LastIndexOf(' ');
        return new
        {
            Name = item.Substring(0, lastSpace).Trim(),
            Status = item.Substring(lastSpace, item.Length - lastSpace).Trim()
        }; }).ToList();
```

Comment: thrown An exception: Length cannot be less than zero.

Comment: item is empty.@Gilad Green

Comment: I got Name: item special I none.included Status.

Comment: result.ForEach(c => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(c.status)); status is empty.I want Name item1,item2,....item special I not item1 actived,item2 none...and item special I none.@Gilad Green

Comment: @Jandy - Still can't understand what is the problem you are staying. If I print to Debug the different statuses I get: "actived", "none", "none", "actived"

Comment: @Jandy - what is the string you are working on? It can't be the same one as from the question above

Comment: lastSpace = 0.I think the issue is space char.@Gilad Green

Comment: @Jandy - you need to decide what you want to do in the case where your row doesn't match what you said at first "text text"..

Comment: your code worked fine.But having a space char in the end of my string "item1 actived" is "item1 actived ".I will fix it later. Thank your solution :)  @Gilad Green